# Windows 7 Aero Taskbar previews not working (no hover/click)

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, aero, aero-peek

I don't know what's wrong or if it's a bug from a recent update but the aero taskbar previews stopped working, I can see the previews but they are unclickable, I can't switch a window through the taskbar previews. Is there a fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Switching to `Windows 7 Basic` theme and to normal one again seems to fix this problem. Still not sure what caused this.